# iOS Java SocketException

Tags: java, ios, post, jvm, socketexception

I'm running a JVM on iOS.

When I try to fetch data using a POST request from a webpage, and the connection can not be established (client sided), I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
  at gnu.java.nio.VMChannel.getpeername(Native Method)
  at gnu.java.nio.VMChannel.getPeerAddress(VMChannel.java:471)
  at gnu.java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.isConnected(SocketChannelImpl.java:194)
  at gnu.java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:216)
  at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.java:218)
  at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcessor.java:198)
  at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProcessor.java:45)
  at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProcessor.java:485)
  at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:743)
```

The code that I use to do the post request (note that data might be an empty string):

```
URL url = new URL(urlstring);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
     .getInputStream()));
```

Also the request is executed in a separate worker-thread. The other functionality of the program is not affected when this happens.

I think it has to do with the JVM that is running. Any idea why that error is thrown? How would you prevent it from showing?

Thank you

Comment: are you trying to use Java to write iOS application?

Comment: And why is GNU's `SocketChannelImpl` calling `getPeerAddress()` in the `isConnected()` method at all? It only has to return a `boolean` maintaining the 'not-yet-connected' state.

Comment: @shivan No, I just use it in the background to run simple server application.

Comment: @EJP No idea. Do you think it has to do with the jre6 I'm using? This seems to be a similar exception: http://www.phidgets.com/phorum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=16155

Comment: You aren't using a JRE at all, you are using some GNU thing. The JRE doesn't contain any GNU code. What does java -version print?

Comment: @EJP you are right, I was looking in the wrong package. Well, I'm running JamVM version 1.5.1. Do you think it would help to update to 1.5.4 (http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @vincent Sorry, I can't help you with any information about JREs other than Oracle's. Good luck. It seems as though the exception is trying to tell you you're not connected, but it's anybody's guess really. `isConnected()` has no business calling any system APIs at all.

Comment: @EJP Why are you saying that isConnected() has no business calling any system API? I found this: http://fossies.org/dox/gcc-4.5.3/classpath_2gnu_2java_2nio_2SocketChannelImpl_8java_source.html#l00186 The exception is (as I wrote) only thrown when the connection is not available. And thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @EJP does it maybe have to do with IPv6 incompatibility? http://fossies.org/dox/gcc-4.5.3/classpath_2vm_2reference_2gnu_2java_2nio_2VMChannel_8java_source.html#l00465

Comment: @vincent See the stack trace. You are getting an exception from `isConnected()`. It isn't specified to throw exceptions, it is specified to return a boolean. I will only add that in my experience GNU CLASSPATH and all its works are to be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @EJP oh I understand. But since (on a different JVM) this is not thrown, it could also be a problem of the JVM? I mean what would happen if getpeername throws an exception it was never supposed to? Or why are you saying it's GNUs fault?

Comment: @vincent It is GNU's fault because (1) they are calling `getPeerName()` at all (Oracle's implementation of `isConnected()` reads something like `{ return isConnected; }`; and (2) either getPeerName() shouldn't throw `InvalidArgumentException` or the calling `isConnected()` method should catch it and treat it as 'not connected'.

Comment: @EJP If you make that into an answer I'll accept it!